# Animating a dead sprite after he collides with something

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I have successfully animated the walking player sprite in the platformer game I am making. When the player collides with a trap I want it to render an image of him dead and not of him walking. Any ideas?

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, x, y, width = 65, height = 35):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.hspeed = 2
    self.vspeed = 0

    self.images = []
    r0 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i1.png")
    r1 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i2.png")
    r2 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i3.png")
    r3 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i4.png")
    hurt = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\Hurt.png")
    self.images.append(r0)
    self.images.append(r1)
    self.images.append(r2)
    self.images.append(r3)

    self.gravity = 0.5
    self.index = 0
    self.image = self.images[self.index]
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,width,height)

    self.TimeNum = 0
    self.TimeTarget = 10

    self.OnGround = False
    self.collision = False

def update(self, BlockListGrass, TrapList):

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] or key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.TimeNum += 1
        if self.TimeNum == self.TimeTarget:
            self.index += 1
            if self.index >= len(self.images):
                self.index = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.index]

            self.TimeNum = 0

    collision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, BlockListGrass, False )
    for each_object in collision:
        if self.vspeed > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = each_object.rect.top
        if self.vspeed < 0:
            self.rect.top = each_object.rect.bottom

    TrapCollision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,TrapList,False )
    for each_object in TrapCollision:
        self.collision = True
        if self.collision == True:
            #not sure what to do here
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another image, instead the sprite is "dead":

```
# In your Player class
dead = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\dead.png")
self.images.append(dead)
```

When your sprite triggers your trap and dies, simply change the picture to `dead`.

```
if self.collision: # It is the same as yur original, just shorter
    self.image = dead
```

Comment: Thanks that all makes sense except the fact that won't the dead animation show up in my walking animation if i add it to that list?

Comment: actually i take that back i just appended the image when i came into collision with trap! thanks for your help

Comment: @Jim, you could just make `self.image` equal to `dead`.